# dynamic numbering of content divs

Tags: wordpress, html, dynamic, parallax

I am working on a wordpress parallax site an want to dynamically add a number to the page/content div based on its order on the page.  Is there a way for me to do this?

```
<div id="container">

<div id="content-1">content from page 1</div>
<div id="content-2">content from page 2</div>
<div id="content-3">content from page 3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What?  Your question is not really clear, please rephrase and try to give more context.  You can do this very easily in PHP or Javascript depending on whether you are talking about adding the numbers while the content is being generated by the server (PHP) or after the fact (Javascript).

Comment: I want to add the numbers while the content is being generated.

Comment: Then that depends on the template code and how the content is generated. If each content div is being generated by the WP loop for example (e.g. posts) you could just add a simple iterator to the loop and echo that in the ID.

Comment: i.e. `<?php $i=0 ?>` before the loop, then inside the loop `<div id="content-<?php echo $i ?>"> [rest of the loop] </div> i++;`

Comment: if you want more specific direction you need to post the PHP template code that generates your page content (just the Loop is fine, e.g. everything between `<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` and `<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`).